# Про JavaScript основы

Tags: javascript

Прошу помогите, почему не работает код (всегда выдает только false). И еще прошу совет - как правильнее найти button в такой ситуации, по тегу думаю не очень, но по классу не получилось.

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="question">
        Футбольный клуб из этого города:
    </span>
    <h1 class="city">
        Мадрид
    </h1>
    <div class="btns">
        <button class="btn" onclick="btn()">Ювентус</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="btn()">Челси</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="btn()">Реал</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="btn()">Бавария</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function btn() {
        let city = document.getElementsByTagName("Button").innerText;
        if (city === "Реал"){
            alert(true);
        }else{
            alert(false);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Множественное число в названии функции getElement**s**ByTagName как бы намекает, что она возвращает не один элемент.

Comment: А ещё использовать `innerText` не рекомендуется, но это к вопросу не относится.

Comment: Если будет несколько вопросов, при таком подходе придется написать отдельную функцию для каждого. Можно отвязать логику от конкретных ответов, например добавить уникальный класс кнопке с правильным ответом. И при клике - проверять наличие класса у кнопки. `onclick="btn(this)";` ... `function btn(elem){ alert( elem.classList.contains('класс-правильности') ); }`

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

советую прочитать про [делегирование](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation), [краткая запись if](https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse)

так же старайтесь не писать обработчики функций прямо в HTML документе

```js
const btns = document.querySelector('.btns'); // выбираем родителя

btns.addEventListener('click', function(e) { // добавляем родителю событие клика
  const btn = e.target.closest('.btn'); // след. 2 строки проверяют, кликнули ли мы на кнопку (.btn), если нет, то ничего не делаем

  if (!btn) return;

  btn.textContent.toLowerCase() === 'реал' ? alert(true) : alert(false); // брать текст лучше через textContent, переводим его в нижний регист, если он совпадает с 'реал' выводим соответсвующий ответ, some ? true : false - краткая запись if
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="question">
        Футбольный клуб из этого города:
    </span>
  <h1 class="city">
    Мадрид
  </h1>
  <div class="btns">
    <button class="btn">Ювентус</button>
    <button class="btn">Челси</button>
    <button class="btn">Реал</button>
    <button class="btn">Бавария</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно сразу `alert( btn.textContent.toLowerCase() === 'реал' );`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, чуток поподробнее описал, но такой вариант тоже вполне уместен)

Comment: Спасибо большое, все понял читая урок про делегирование. В бутстрапе часто копировал код с подобными функциями, но сейчас начиная учить Javascript, уже становиться понятнее конструкция! Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ESargsyan, не за что, желаю успехов!